# Custom Stores for Customers

Tags: multistore

We are looking for a way to offer our customers the ability to register with our site and create their own store on our site.

An example would be at the following page.
https://www.shapeways.com/shops/raphaelvertices

If you notice they have a URL with their name in it and the ability to show a custom banner image with a list of all of the products that they sell on that site as well as contact info etc.

We need similar functionality to allow our product providers to list their products in their own store to be sold and marketed by us.

Any suggestions on how to create this functionality are welcomed even if we have to program an extension ourselves we just need to know its possible to do with Magento and if there are any preexisting extensions that provide this.

Comment: BuddyPress is a social community platform.  Im not seeing how this is similar to my needs.  Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly easily done and I've seen a number of stores that work on this premise.

Eg.

Any customer can add products via a form on their account, and manage it with a simple grid. Fullfilllment, invoicing and shipping is completed by Magento admins themselves, then the customers (the listee) either dispatch direct to the buyer, or dispatch to the Magento owner, who in turn despatches it to the buyer.

The principle is easy, as you have outlined, you need only a single attribute set on the product to track the listee (ie. the customer ID).

On the frontend, filtering collections by attribute (ie. Shop by manfacturer) is possible.

The only things you have to be aware of is listing quality validation, your catalogue size will grow continually (so housekeeping would have to be done) and tha there will be quite a bit of custom development required to achieve the end result you desire.